# Getting a Twilio 404 Error Rails Receiving SMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio

I'm trying to create an app that accepts an SMS message through Twilio, and then creates a check-in/out transaction that is tied to both employee models and item models. A simple SMS-based item checkout/checkin tracker. I have the twilio app wired up to listen on tooler.herokuapp.com/twilio/twilio_create, but when I send messages to the number, nothing happens and I get a 404 error within twilio's logs. Not sure exactly what's going on, was hoping someone might be able to help. In this case, I'm taking the FROM from twilio and putting it into employee_id, and the BODY from twilio and putting it into item_id. Why won't it create new transactions?

db/schema.rb

```
    ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130516162824) do

      create_table "employees", :force => true do |t|
        t.string   "phone"
        t.string   "name"
        t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
        t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
      end

      create_table "items", :force => true do |t|
        t.string   "description"
        t.string   "assettag"
        t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
        t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
      end

      create_table "transactions", :force => true do |t|
        t.boolean  "status"
        t.integer  "item_id"
        t.integer  "employee_id"
        t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
        t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
      end

      add_index "transactions", ["employee_id"], :name => "index_transactions_on_employee_id"
      add_index "transactions", ["item_id"], :name => "index_transactions_on_item_id"

      create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
        t.string   "email",                  :default => "", :null => false
        t.string   "encrypted_password",     :default => "", :null => false
        t.string   "reset_password_token"
        t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
        t.datetime "remember_created_at"
        t.integer  "sign_in_count",          :default => 0
        t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
        t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
        t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
        t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
        t.datetime "created_at",                             :null => false
        t.datetime "updated_at",                             :null => false
      end

      add_index "users", ["email"], :name => "index_users_on_email", :unique => true
      add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], :name => "index_users_on_reset_password_token", :unique => true

    end
```

app/controllers/twilio_controller.rb

```
    class TwilioController < ApplicationController

      def process_sms
        @city = params[:FromCity].capitalize
        @state = params[:FromState]
          render 'process_sms.xml.erb', :content_type => 'text/xml'
        end

      def twilio_create
        @transaction = Transaction.new(:item_id => params[:Body], :employee_id => params[:From])
        @transaction.save
      end

    end
```

app/views/twilio/twilio_create.xml.erb

```
<Response>                                                                                                                 
  <Sms>Received. You checked out <%= @body %>, <%= @from %> you lucky bastard.</Sms>
</Response>
```

I already got it working with the process_sms page, so I know that it's something with the twilio_create function. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should the URL be `tooler.herokuapp.com/twilio/twilio_create.xml`? You can check `rake routes` to see all URLs that conforms to your `config/routes.rb`.

Actually, Rails already has CRUD convention. Since you are creating a twilio resource, your `config/routes.rb` should be:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :twilio do
  collection do
    get :process_sms
  end
end
```

In the controller, you should use `def create` instead of `def twilio_create`.

```
class TwilioController < ApplicationController

  def process_sms
    @city = params[:FromCity].capitalize
    @state = params[:FromState]
      render 'process_sms.xml.erb', :content_type => 'text/xml'
    end

  def create
    @transaction = Transaction.new(:item_id => params[:Body], :employee_id => params[:From])
    @transaction.save
  end

end
```

Lastly, rename `app/views/twilio/twilio_create.xml.erb` to `app/views/twilio/create.xml.erb`.

In order to create a new transaction, do a `post` request to `tooler.herokuapp.com/twilio.xml`. That URL will hit the `def create` in `TwilioController` and render `app/views/twilio/create.xml.erb`.

If it still doesn't work because of 404 error, you can check `rake routes` to see all URLs that conforms to your `config/routes.rb`.

Comment: Tried that... this is what I got:

ERROR HTTP retrieval failure
returned the HTTP status code 500.

AccountSid AC403799e6989feb71259aff925d6d6b17
ApiVersion 2010-04-01
Body Huh
From +17177564437
FromCity HARRISBURG
FromCountry US
FromState PA
FromZip 17307
SmsMessageSid SMaa17fbe4cc6a1afb29bff8c5921e4867
SmsSid SMaa17fbe4cc6a1afb29bff8c5921e4867
SmsStatus received
To +17177395006
ToCity SPRING GROVE
ToCountry US
ToState PA
ToZip 17404

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>We're sorry, but something went wrong (500)</title>

Comment: That's from the logs on Twilio, the debugger section. Tried what you recommended and it didn't pan out. Rake routes looks good, I have a POST entry for /twilio that ends with twilio#create. I used to be getting 404's, now they're 500's.

Comment: And now I can't create normal transactions through the web interface - I scaffolded the original model for transactions, just to make sure that I got the relationships right... now when I try to create one by hand through the web app it errors out.

Comment: I was being dumb. I was passing in phone number as an employee_id, but there was no employee id that matched. That's why it was erroring out. Thank you for the help, I get it now.